# c++ MS Word - OleAutomation

Tags: c++, ms-word, automation, office-interop, ole

I am creating `IDispatch` like this:

```
IDispatch *m_pWApp = NULL;
CoInitialize(NULL);
CLSID clsid;
m_hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"Word.Application", &clsid);
if(SUCCEEDED(m_hr))
{

    m_hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_IDispatch, (void **)&m_pWApp);
    if(FAILED(m_hr)) m_pWApp=NULL;
}
```

I am using this to automate word like in [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34998/MS-Office-OLE-Automation-Using-C)

But now I need to use method from interface `IOleCommandTarget::Exec` for hide menu bar for opening word. I know that with this method it is possible.

My question is, how can I get `IOleCommandTarget` to use it for calling Exec and of course to have possibility to use `IDispatch` line in example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, just add:

```
LPOLECOMMANDTARGET lpOleCommandTarget = NULL;
lpDispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IOleCommandTarget, (void**)&lpOleCommandTarget);
```

or

```
IOleCommandTarget* target;
disp->QueryInterface (IID_IOleCommandTarget, (void **) &target);
```

Then `**lpOleCommandTarget->Exec(...);**`

For example:

```
lpOleCommandTarget->Exec(NULL, OLECMDID_PRINT, 0, NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: This returns me E_NOINTERFACE.

Comment: You need to find correct IID for OleCommandTarget, QueryInterface's first parameter, for your OLE object.

Comment: See http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/misc/article.php/c2667/Active-Document-Containers.htm

Comment: I think, that my problem is that I open word as "Word.Application". When I use "Word.Document" than I get IID_IOleCommandTarget. But I need to open word as Word.Application. Is another way how can I hide menu bar or for example disable special control of menu bar "File" ?

Comment: I believe you can hide menu bar etc. That would be a different question. Do some googling and I believe you would find the way to do it. You might have to use Spy++ to locate the classes and windows and hide them.

Comment: I am googling a lot before but I can't find anything which works.

Comment: It's going to require some manual work, SendMessage API and locating the toolbars class and window names. I don't have Windows and Office, I will give it a shot later when I get access to those. I recommend you posting a separate question for hiding toolbar, you might get faster response.

Comment: I tried it and got nothing.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632882/c-hide-menu-bar-and-ribbon-for-ms-word
I will wait. But I don't want to hide toolbar, but menu bar.

Comment: In your question have some code snippet which does have IOleCommandTarget interface

Comment: I don't get IOleCommandTarget when I open word as Word.Application. I need to open word as Word.Application, no Word.Document.